# Click on links that are dynamically loaded using python selenium when scrolling down till the end of a webpage when there is no "more" button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, infinite-scroll, webdriverwait

Consider this I am clicking on the links(that open up problems) using link_text. My aim is to access the problems via these links. However, another set of links load dynamically(without clicking any button) as a part of the webpage after we reach the end of it. I want to click on a link that is not visible in the browser initially, but is visible only after loading the contents of the webpage after scrolling to the end. I also want to access links that may appear after reaching the end of the page 5-6 times.

```
driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms")
    for i in range(20):
        body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(2)
```

or

```
driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms")
for i in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Problem: Clearly this isn't very efficient and at the same time doesn't load all the links.

Desired Behaviour: Should load all these links at once(make it a static webpage with all links visible at once) so that a desired link is always visible and hence can be clicked.

Comment: loading all links at once may not be possible...  it depends on the site, but some will unload the top parts when the page reaches a certain size.   It's not real clear what you are trying to do, but some of this will be out of your control.  You might try to find a button or control on the page that allows you to display all links, or take a look at the scripts they are using to see if you can hack it somehow by executing your own script calls.

Answer (score 0):

To collect all the dynamically loaded links scrolling till the end you have to `scrollDown` and wait for the new elements to render within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms')
  myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h4.challengecard-title"))))
  while True:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      try:
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4.challengecard-title")) > myLength)
          my_titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4.challengecard-title")
          myLength = len(my_titles)
      except TimeoutException:
          break
  for title in my_titles:
      print(title.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Solve Me First
  EasyMax Score: 1Success Rate: 98.43%
  Simple Array Sum
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 93.99%
  Compare the Triplets
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 94.34%
  A Very Big Sum
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 98.63%
  Diagonal Difference
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 95.71%
  Plus Minus
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 98.17%
  Staircase
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 98.06%
  Mini-Max Sum
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 93.11%
  Birthday Cake Candles
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 96.28%
  Time Conversion
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 90.21%
  Grading Students
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 96.59%
  Apple and Orange
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 95.52%
  Kangaroo
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 88.35%
  Between Two Sets
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 88.56%
  Breaking the Records
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 98.28%
  Birthday Chocolate
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 93.30%
  Divisible Sum Pairs
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 97.58%
  Migratory Birds
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 90.55%
  Day of the Programmer
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 88.31%
  Bon Appétit
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 97.74%
  Sock Merchant
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 91.38%
  Drawing Book
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 89.27%
  Counting Valleys
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 94.11%
  Electronics Shop
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 90.88%
  Cats and a Mouse
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 97.60%
  Forming a Magic Square
  MediumMax Score: 20Success Rate: 73.26%
  Picking Numbers
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 88.78%
  Climbing the Leaderboard
  MediumMax Score: 20Success Rate: 55.01%
  The Hurdle Race
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 98.62%
  Designer PDF Viewer
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 98.32%
  Utopian Tree
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 97.33%
  Angry Professor
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 95.52%
  Beautiful Days at the Movies
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 95.79%
  Viral Advertising
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 98.52%
  Save the Prisoner!
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 78.04%
  Circular Array Rotation
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 78.22%
  Sequence Equation
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 96.19%
  Jumping on the Clouds: Revisited
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 96.12%
  Find Digits
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 96.12%
  Extra Long Factorials
  MediumMax Score: 20Success Rate: 95.04%
  Append and Delete
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 66.55%
  Sherlock and Squares
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 84.37%
  Library Fine
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 87.26%
  Cut the sticks
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 94.20%
  Non-Divisible Subset
  MediumMax Score: 20Success Rate: 59.41%
  Repeated String
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 89.20%
  Jumping on the Clouds
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 93.45%
  Equalize the Array
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 93.52%
  Queen's Attack II
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 61.67%
  ACM ICPC Team
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 87.97%
  Taum and B'day
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 89.05%
  Organizing Containers of Balls
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 80.55%
  Encryption
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 90.97%
  Bigger is Greater
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 77.89%
  Modified Kaprekar Numbers
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 87.08%
  Beautiful Triplets
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 90.27%
  Minimum Distances
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 93.69%
  Halloween Sale
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 88.15%
  The Time in Words
  MediumMax Score: 25Success Rate: 93.01%
  Chocolate Feast
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 90.33%
  Service Lane
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 97.25%
  Lisa's Workbook
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 90.55%
  Flatland Space Stations
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 81.37%
  Fair Rations
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 90.31%
  Cavity Map
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 90.13%
  Manasa and Stones
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 90.04%
  The Grid Search
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 74.28%
  Happy Ladybugs
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 82.66%
  Strange Counter
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 78.72%
  3D Surface Area
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 91.97%
  Absolute Permutation
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 73.62%
  The Bomberman Game
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 64.95%
  Ema's Supercomputer
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 63.88%
  Larry's Array
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 77.87%
  Almost Sorted
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 71.59%
  Matrix Layer Rotation
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 75.10%
  Big Sorting
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 63.67%
  Super Reduced String
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 86.71%
  Intro to Tutorial Challenges
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 98.15%
  CamelCase
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 98.02%
  Insertion Sort - Part 1
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 86.86%
  Strong Password
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 83.89%
  Two Characters
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 75.14%
  Insertion Sort - Part 2
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 96.95%
  Correctness and the Loop Invariant
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 98.56%
  Caesar Cipher
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 85.39%
  Mars Exploration
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 94.38%
  Running Time of Algorithms
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 96.32%
  HackerRank in a String!
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 91.36%
  Quicksort 1 - Partition
  EasyMax Score: 10Success Rate: 95.70%
  Pangrams
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 94.44%
  Weighted Uniform Strings
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 73.63%
  Separate the Numbers
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 87.73%
  Funny String
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 93.97%
  Counting Sort 1
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 95.74%
  Counting Sort 2
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 96.68%
  Gemstones
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 93.08%
  Alternating Characters
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 96.70%
  The Full Counting Sort
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 82.43%
  Beautiful Binary String
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 94.92%
  Closest Numbers
  EasyMax Score: 35Success Rate: 87.66%
  The Love-Letter Mystery
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 96.27%
  Find the Median
  EasyMax Score: 35Success Rate: 87.81%
  Determining DNA Health
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 11.73%
  Insertion Sort Advanced Analysis
  AdvancedMax Score: 50Success Rate: 35.02%
  Palindrome Index
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 66.07%
  Fraudulent Activity Notifications
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 38.94%
  Anagram
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 89.25%
  Making Anagrams
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 92.39%
  Lily's Homework
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 49.25%
  Game of Thrones - I
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 93.41%
  Two Strings
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 88.41%
  String Construction
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 94.40%
  Sherlock and the Valid String
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 63.38%
  Highest Value Palindrome
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 51.83%
  Maximum Palindromes
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 31.93%
  Sherlock and Anagrams
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 86.37%
  Common Child
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 57.38%
  Bear and Steady Gene
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 61.39%
  Morgan and a String
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 28.74%
  Count Strings
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 70.33%
  String Function Calculation
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 31.79%
  Build a Palindrome
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 28.15%
  Build a String
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 17.23%
  Gridland Provinces
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 31.44%
  Cards Permutation
  ExpertMax Score: 85Success Rate: 35.55%
  Ashton and String
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 35.79%
  String Similarity
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 22.47%
  Super Functional Strings
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 20.05%
  Circular Palindromes
  AdvancedMax Score: 120Success Rate: 29.67%
  Similar Strings
  AdvancedMax Score: 85Success Rate: 15.98%
  Save Humanity
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 12.62%
  Find Strings
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 21.83%
  Palindromic Border
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 34.97%
  Two Two
  AdvancedMax Score: 150Success Rate: 37.09%
  Two Strings Game
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 45.09%
  Letter Islands
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 32.97%
  Pseudo-Isomorphic Substrings
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 50.36%
  How Many Substrings?
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 6.00%
  Hackerland Radio Transmitters
  MediumMax Score: 25Success Rate: 62.79%
  Gridland Metro
  MediumMax Score: 25Success Rate: 42.20%
  Ice Cream Parlor
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 92.50%
  KnightL on a Chessboard
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 86.88%
  Minimum Loss
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 59.65%
  Missing Numbers
  EasyMax Score: 45Success Rate: 83.54%
  Pairs
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 75.38%
  Sherlock and Array
  EasyMax Score: 40Success Rate: 79.76%
  Maximum Subarray Sum
  HardMax Score: 65Success Rate: 29.76%
  Connected Cells in a Grid
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 87.24%
  Short Palindrome
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 56.58%
  Maximizing Mission Points
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 35.63%
  Count Luck
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 84.96%
  Cut the Tree
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 70.68%
  Making Candies
  HardMax Score: 45Success Rate: 44.00%
  Gena Playing Hanoi
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 58.72%
  Beautiful Quadruples
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 36.72%
  Red Knight's Shortest Path
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 80.88%
  Bike Racers
  HardMax Score: 65Success Rate: 33.49%
  Task Scheduling
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 36.76%
  Similar Pair
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 35.16%
  Absolute Element Sums
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 23.88%
  Almost Integer Rock Garden
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 41.13%
  Sorted Subsegments
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 9.12%
  Distant Pairs
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 18.30%
  King Richard's Knights
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 35.26%
  Frog in Maze
  HardMax Score: 65Success Rate: 29.47%
  Roads and Libraries
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 63.69%
  Journey to the Moon
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 62.92%
  Synchronous Shopping
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 49.67%
  Subset Component
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 54.95%
  Breadth First Search: Shortest Reach
  MediumMax Score: 55Success Rate: 77.80%
  Kruskal (MST): Really Special Subtree
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 82.60%
  Even Tree
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 89.00%
  Snakes and Ladders: The Quickest Way Up
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 76.61%
  Dijkstra: Shortest Reach 2
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 57.14%
  The Story of a Tree
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 47.11%
  Prim's (MST) : Special Subtree
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 82.26%
  Toll Cost Digits
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 42.69%
  Real Estate Broker
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 47.28%
  Clique
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 55.97%
  Minimum Penalty Path
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 47.72%
  Demanding Money
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 32.88%
  The Value of Friendship
  HardMax Score: 55Success Rate: 42.23%
  Coprime Paths
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 34.89%
  Minimum MST Graph
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 35.58%
  Jack goes to Rapture
  MediumMax Score: 80Success Rate: 58.50%
  Crab Graphs
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 67.77%
  Bead Ornaments
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 77.25%
  Jeanie's Route
  MediumMax Score: 80Success Rate: 63.61%
  Floyd : City of Blinding Lights
  HardMax Score: 75Success Rate: 80.73%
  Roads in HackerLand
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 38.00%
  Kingdom Connectivity
  HardMax Score: 75Success Rate: 50.16%
  Computer Game
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 14.95%
  Rust & Murderer
  MediumMax Score: 70Success Rate: 54.66%
  Problem solving
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 37.07%
  Journey Scheduling
  HardMax Score: 75Success Rate: 54.15%
  Matrix
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 61.41%
  Recording Episodes
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 40.17%
  Repair Roads
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 40.94%
  Kth Ancestor
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 48.09%
  ByteLandian Tours
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 55.38%
  Find the Path
  HardMax Score: 75Success Rate: 21.45%
  Savita And Friends
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 66.67%
  Liars
  AdvancedMax Score: 85Success Rate: 49.59%
  Jumping Rooks
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 39.80%
  Tripartite Matching
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 35.76%
  Tree Flow
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 25.49%
  DAG Queries
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 11.41%
  Favorite sequence
  AdvancedMax Score: 95Success Rate: 39.86%
  Jogging Cats
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 29.88%
  Quadrant Queries
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 27.94%
  Hacker Country
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 38.07%
  HackerX
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 35.01%
  Huarongdao
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 17.70%
  Training the army
  HardMax Score: 120Success Rate: 56.22%
  Jim and his LAN Party
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 47.25%
  Travel in HackerLand
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 44.64%
  Alex vs Fedor
  ExpertMax Score: 150Success Rate: 62.58%
  Vertical Paths
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 68.91%
  Drive
  ExpertMax Score: 90Success Rate: 30.73%
  Travelling Salesman in a Grid
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 18.22%
  Road Network
  ExpertMax Score: 90Success Rate: 57.27%
  Going to the Office
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 20.87%
  Tree Splitting
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 40.23%
  Ticket
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 34.96%
  DFS Edges
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 66.15%
  Diameter Minimization
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 50.45%
  Airports
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 69.35%
  Definite Random Walks
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 66.91%
  Minimum Absolute Difference in an Array
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 85.21%
  Marc's Cakewalk
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 95.48%
  Grid Challenge
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 82.30%
  Luck Balance
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 92.02%
  Maximum Perimeter Triangle
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 89.89%
  Beautiful Pairs
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 75.05%
  Candies
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 65.89%
  Sherlock and The Beast
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 81.93%
  Priyanka and Toys
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 89.71%
  Largest Permutation
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 61.38%
  Mark and Toys
  EasyMax Score: 35Success Rate: 92.19%
  Greedy Florist
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 93.49%
  Max Min
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 84.11%
  Jim and the Orders
  EasyMax Score: 40Success Rate: 88.23%
  Permuting Two Arrays
  EasyMax Score: 40Success Rate: 93.41%
  Cutting Boards
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 74.18%
  Reverse Shuffle Merge
  AdvancedMax Score: 50Success Rate: 41.62%
  Goodland Electricity
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 62.51%
  Cloudy Day
  MediumMax Score: 45Success Rate: 27.97%
  Chief Hopper
  HardMax Score: 65Success Rate: 73.01%
  Sherlock and MiniMax
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 49.75%
  Accessory Collection
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 22.20%
  Team Formation
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 32.69%
  Fighting Pits
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 37.64%
  Lena Sort
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 38.83%
  The Coin Change Problem
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 76.93%
  Equal
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 48.27%
  Flipping the Matrix
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 88.80%
  Sherlock and Cost
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 63.11%
  Gaming Array
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 75.16%
  New Year Chaos
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 62.93%
  Construct the Array
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 60.39%
  Bonetrousle
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 45.67%
  Kingdom Division
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 49.08%
  Yet Another KMP Problem
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 56.04%
  Sam and substrings
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 56.71%
  Beautiful 3 Set
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 46.30%
  Fibonacci Modified
  MediumMax Score: 45Success Rate: 80.02%
  Inverse RMQ
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 56.13%
  Abbreviation
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 39.64%
  Two Subarrays
  ExpertMax Score: 70Success Rate: 17.51%
  Prime XOR
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 50.67%
  Lovely Triplets
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 65.57%
  Array Construction
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 50.80%
  Decibinary Numbers
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 38.91%
  Fair Cut
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 46.37%
  The Maximum Subarray
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 75.29%
  Angry Children 2
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 43.60%
  Sherlock's Array Merging Algorithm
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 50.26%
  Prime Digit Sums
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 35.45%
  HackerRank City
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 67.45%
  Summing Pieces
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 47.75%
  Mr K marsh
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 46.20%
  Substring Diff
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 64.66%
  Xor and Sum
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 78.80%
  Lego Blocks
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 74.54%
  Brick Tiling
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 58.84%
  Alien Languages
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 49.81%
  Stock Maximize
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 81.92%
  Two Robots
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 38.57%
  Cut Tree
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 56.66%
  Tara's Beautiful Permutations
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 55.74%
  Wet Shark and Two Subsequences
  MediumMax Score: 80Success Rate: 44.59%
  Nikita and the Game
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 59.38%
  Choosing White Balls
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 26.74%
  Mandragora Forest
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 70.51%
  Red John is Back
  MediumMax Score: 65Success Rate: 79.60%
  LCS Returns
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 33.99%
  Grid Walking
  MediumMax Score: 55Success Rate: 45.40%
  Matrix Land
  HardMax Score: 55Success Rate: 46.50%
  Knapsack
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 79.25%
  Bricks Game
  MediumMax Score: 55Success Rate: 78.47%
  The Longest Increasing Subsequence
  AdvancedMax Score: 60Success Rate: 38.64%
  Coin on the Table
  MediumMax Score: 65Success Rate: 67.02%
  The Longest Common Subsequence
  MediumMax Score: 55Success Rate: 46.26%
  Play with words
  MediumMax Score: 65Success Rate: 68.28%
  Black and White Tree
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 31.67%
  Counting Special Sub-Cubes
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 57.70%
  Interval Selection
  MediumMax Score: 65Success Rate: 60.48%
  String Reduction
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 59.59%
  Far Vertices
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 52.47%
  Counting Road Networks
  ExpertMax Score: 90Success Rate: 38.55%
  Superman Celebrates Diwali
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 68.10%
  Hexagonal Grid
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 78.14%
  Queens on Board
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 47.10%
  Shashank and the Palindromic Strings
  AdvancedMax Score: 60Success Rate: 52.53%
  Points in a Plane
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 39.18%
  Turn Off the Lights
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 51.63%
  Animal Transport
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 64.22%
  The Indian Job
  MediumMax Score: 70Success Rate: 49.60%
  Requirement
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 34.76%
  A Super Hero
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 39.02%
  Clues on a Binary Path
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 26.09%
  Road Maintenance
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 34.71%
  Billboards
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 33.40%
  Beautiful Strings
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 21.50%
  Covering the stains
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 65.09%
  GCD Matrix
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 26.43%
  Fairy Chess
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 43.66%
  Suffix Rotation
  ExpertMax Score: 80Success Rate: 23.41%
  New Year Present
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 17.62%
  Travel around the world
  MediumMax Score: 120Success Rate: 41.09%
  Longest Palindromic Subsequence
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 15.54%
  Candles Counting
  MediumMax Score: 85Success Rate: 37.50%
  Hyper Strings
  AdvancedMax Score: 90Success Rate: 31.44%
  Swap Permutation
  MediumMax Score: 85Success Rate: 48.59%
  Extremum Permutations
  MediumMax Score: 100Success Rate: 50.54%
  Square Subsequences
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 52.67%
  Dorsey Thief
  AdvancedMax Score: 85Success Rate: 34.80%
  Mining
  AdvancedMax Score: 75Success Rate: 28.75%
  Police Operation
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 37.27%
  Zurikela's Graph
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 66.67%
  Modify The Sequence
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 15.70%
  Longest Mod Path
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 55.19%
  P-sequences
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 46.90%
  Robot
  AdvancedMax Score: 120Success Rate: 27.99%
  Lucky Numbers
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 16.60%
  Unfair Game
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 30.57%
  Oil Well
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 33.24%
  Find the Seed
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 25.24%
  The Blacklist
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 42.88%
  Tree Pruning
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 43.36%
  Ones and Twos
  HardMax Score: 100Success Rate: 21.04%
  Count Scorecards
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 24.79%
  Vim War
  AdvancedMax Score: 120Success Rate: 41.94%
  Best spot
  AdvancedMax Score: 100Success Rate: 23.77%
  Divisible Numbers
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 5.97%
  Unique Divide And Conquer
  AdvancedMax Score: 90Success Rate: 37.37%
  King and Four Sons
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 34.55%
  Dortmund Dilemma
  AdvancedMax Score: 150Success Rate: 75.64%
  Super Kth LIS
  AdvancedMax Score: 90Success Rate: 28.88%
  Counting the Ways
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 25.06%
  Hard Disk Drives
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 39.57%
  Separate the chocolate
  ExpertMax Score: 250Success Rate: 57.09%
  Lonely Integer
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 96.32%
  Maximizing XOR
  EasyMax Score: 30Success Rate: 96.77%
  Counter game
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 67.08%
  Xor-sequence
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 52.47%
  Sum vs XOR
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 68.46%
  The Great XOR
  MediumMax Score: 25Success Rate: 70.40%
  Flipping bits
  EasyMax Score: 40Success Rate: 95.56%
  Yet Another Minimax Problem
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 37.26%
  Sansa and XOR
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 81.54%
  AND Product
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 54.15%
  Winning Lottery Ticket
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 47.12%
  Xoring Ninja
  HardMax Score: 55Success Rate: 55.83%
  Cipher
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 75.00%
  XOR Matrix
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 27.70%
  What's Next?
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 42.76%
  String Transmission
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 53.19%
  A or B
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 66.71%
  Manipulative Numbers
  HardMax Score: 55Success Rate: 43.59%
  Stone Game
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 42.04%
  2's complement
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 39.20%
  Changing Bits
  AdvancedMax Score: 70Success Rate: 35.56%
  XOR key
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 22.64%
  Maximizing the Function
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 29.09%
  XOR Subsequences
  AdvancedMax Score: 80Success Rate: 32.11%
  Iterate It
  ExpertMax Score: 90Success Rate: 9.82%
  Hamming Distance
  ExpertMax Score: 150Success Rate: 40.43%
  Mixing proteins
  HardMax Score: 80Success Rate: 36.69%
  The Power Sum
  MediumMax Score: 20Success Rate: 89.86%
  Crossword Puzzle
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 80.58%
  Recursive Digit Sum
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 69.83%
  Simplified Chess Engine
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 53.35%
  Password Cracker
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 40.88%
  Arithmetic Expressions
  HardMax Score: 40Success Rate: 44.11%
  Stone Division, Revisited
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 57.03%
  K Factorization
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 76.53%
  Bowling Pins
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 35.26%
  Simplified Chess Engine II
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 64.16%
  Repetitive K-Sums
  AdvancedMax Score: 150Success Rate: 58.30%
  Game of Stones
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 87.12%
  Tower Breakers
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 85.76%
  A Chessboard Game
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 89.02%
  Introduction to Nim Game
  EasyMax Score: 15Success Rate: 81.67%
  Misère Nim
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 75.07%
  Nimble Game
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 68.29%
  Alice and Bob's Silly Game
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 72.13%
  Poker Nim
  EasyMax Score: 20Success Rate: 85.71%
  Tower Breakers, Revisited!
  MediumMax Score: 25Success Rate: 57.14%
  Tower Breakers, Again!
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 54.19%
  Zero-Move Nim
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 53.25%
  Chessboard Game, Again!
  MediumMax Score: 30Success Rate: 64.49%
  Digits Square Board
  MediumMax Score: 35Success Rate: 56.60%
  Fun Game
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 52.26%
  Stone Division
  HardMax Score: 50Success Rate: 41.80%
  Chocolate in Box
  MediumMax Score: 70Success Rate: 74.10%
  Kitty and Katty
  MediumMax Score: 80Success Rate: 68.81%
  Powers Game
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 71.93%
  Deforestation
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 49.47%
  Bob and Ben
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 74.33%
  Tower Breakers - The Final Battle
  MediumMax Score: 50Success Rate: 51.68%
  Simple Game
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 37.93%
  Permutation game
  MediumMax Score: 70Success Rate: 71.18%
  Move the Coins
  HardMax Score: 60Success Rate: 62.56%
  Play on benders
  MediumMax Score: 70Success Rate: 69.91%
  New Year Game
  MediumMax Score: 60Success Rate: 50.54%
  Stone Piles
  HardMax Score: 85Success Rate: 61.42%
  Chocolate Game
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 33.12%
  The Prime Game
  HardMax Score: 90Success Rate: 62.81%
  Vertical Rooks
  MediumMax Score: 90Success Rate: 67.62%
  A stones game
  MediumMax Score: 90Success Rate: 67.72%
  Tastes Like Winning
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 28.50%
  Walking the Approximate Longest Path
  HardMax Score: 70Success Rate: 72.97%
  Sam's Puzzle (Approximate)
  AdvancedMax Score: 85Success Rate: 41.45%
  Spies, Revised
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 2.78%
  TBS Problem
  ExpertMax Score: 100Success Rate: 7.14%
  Prime Dates
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 77.87%
  Minimum Operations
  MediumMax Score: 45Success Rate: 63.67%
  XOR Strings
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 92.34%
  Zig Zag Sequence
  MediumMax Score: 40Success Rate: 88.85%
  Smart Number
  EasyMax Score: 25Success Rate: 82.38%
  ```